# set focus on particular element with keyboard keys using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have 10 texboxes in one page & want to get focus of particular texbox by just pressing particular key on keyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: what have you tried? what issue you have landed on?

Comment: You can use `tabindex` property in html. Use `tab` key to focus it.

Comment: you can use the window.onkeyup function to listen for keypresses, then inspect which key has been pressed and set the focus to the desired element

Comment: @KiranDash I didn't tried anything because I don't know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: @ThomasPowell can you show me example in answer?

Comment: @SUN . It is possible. Have a look at the duplicate mentioned by Cerbrus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Listen to keyboard events, just call `$("#item_id").focus()` inside your keyevent handler